# Create a static hyperlink from a cellReference hyperlink in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm not sure of the correct terminology so I'm going to use a quick (1 min 4 seconds) screencast video to explain it.

https://youtu.be/Wi5H5NnYs3s

Basically, I want to create a hyperlink function with static values in column D that is an exact clone of the hyperlink function in column C (that was made with cell reference). I need this so I can easily copy/paste the created link from one cell to another or into another application. Currently, I can't do that because column C uses cell referenced values.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Linked Example**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HdPzWocCaTL0-GtbP4A_IKp0-oG6vKL1VsF9b8oleOg/edit#gid=0

Comment: My inclination would be to write a script to create the hyperlink. Is this just a one-off task, or something that you need to do repetitively?

Comment: It will be done four times a year for roughly 80 links.

Comment: Then, write a script using `setFormula`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **E1** cell and try to copy-paste the stuff around:

```
={"NEW APPROACH :)"; ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(B2:B, A2:A))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't accomplish what I need. I need to see the Label with the URL hyperlinked to it. I also need to be able to copy/paste it (so no cell references).

Comment: thanks again for updating your answer, it still doesn't address the "copy/paste" portion of my problem. I need to be able to copy the result in cell E2 and paste it into another cell (like G10) and it should still work. So I basically need E2 to be built using static values, not cell references.

Comment: @Mr.B did you try it? proposed solution accounts for that if the formula sits above the array. paste in F1 `={"xx"; ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(B2:B, A2:A))}` copy F2, paste wherever you need

Comment: you are correct, I was testing it on the actual formula and not the next row down. THANKS!!!